# Display local Avatars for Post Authors in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, avatar, gravatar

My wordPress is Multi-author site. How can I show a Local Avatar image for Post Authors only instead of a Gravatar in the Authors Page, Blog Post and even in the comments by the Post Author.

Tried with below function with `get_avatar` filter to replace Post Authors Gravatar with Local Avatars but not working.

Need help in making the below code corrected & work:

```
add_filter('get_avatar', 'author_avatar', 1, 5);

function author_avatar($avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt) {
    global $post, $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    if ($current_user->ID == $post->post_author) {
       $author_avatar = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/author-slug.png';
}
return $get_avatar;
}
```

Comment: Please explain in detail, what is that you intend to do and what is not working. Also what is return $get_avatar supposed to do? I don't see $get_avatar variable anywhere?

Comment: @Esko, I have updated my question. My coding knowledge is limited so need help.

Comment: There is a plugin called "WP User Avatar" which allows you to use any image from your WP media collection as a local avatar for a user - works well in my experience.

Comment: Thanks for the Plugin suggestion. But, can we make this code work?